# change the number of items visible in the first scroll in combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sapui5

I am using SAPUI5 framework. I have a combo box in the view which has 20 items in it. When I open the combo box 8 items are visible, for the remaining items I have to scroll down. Is there any way that I can make the number of items visible in the combo box list as 11 and for the remaining I will have to scroll down?

[image: Image of the combo box]

I have tried to change the scroll properties of the `div` in which the combo box list is getting rendered

Is there any way we can do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can set maxPopupItems to 11.

Comment: i cant find the property maxpopupitesm in sap.m.combobox

Comment: maxPopupItems is a property of the deprecated control sap.ui.commons.ComboBox. It's deprecated sind 1.38. In sap.m.combobox such a property does not exist. If you want to use such a feature you have to dvelop your own custom control based on sap.m.comobox.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it, however it is definitely not the standard approach. There is no property in the ComboBox control which will allow this. So here's a quick hack.

```
var oCombo = this.byId("MyComboBox"),
    oList = oCombo._oList,
    oPopOver = oList.getParent();
oPopOver.setContentHeight("440px"); //Shows about 11 items
```

When you try to select a value inside a Combobox, it will create a PopOver control inside which is a List control. You can set the height to this Popover by getting the reference to the internal List object of which the PopOver is a parent.